# C++: pass by temporary value not work, how to fix it?

Tags: c++

```
Slice {
  Slice(const std::string s): data_(s.data()), n_(s.size()) {}
}

std::string get_str(){
  return "abcdefg";
}

void main(){
  Slice s1("abcdefg");
  printf("%s\n", s1.data()); // output: works fine

  Slice s2(get_str());
  printf("%s\n", s2.data()); // output: doesn't work
}
```

Haven't use C++ for quite a long time, can't understand what's going on here, can anyone help to **explain** and give some advices?

Comment: What is `Slice`? Please post a [mcve].

Comment: Show an ACTUAL definition of `Slice`  i.e. one that has the member function `data()` that returns something that can be passed to `printf()`as they are in `main()`.    And, BTW, `main()` returns `int`, not `void`, in standard C++.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Neither of these are legal, since in both cases they save off `.data()` referring to a temporary (the `const std::string s` argument that stops existing as soon as the constructor returns).

The fact that the first case works is pure coincidence (the memory in question hasn't been reused yet), but it's still undefined behavior.

The only way to make this work is:

1. Receive the argument to the constructor by reference, and ensure it exists as variable in the caller's scope for at least as long as the `Slice` exists:

   ```
   Slice {
     // Now receives by const reference
     Slice(const std::string& s): data_(s.data()), n_(s.size()) {}
   }

   std::string get_str(){
     return "abcdefg";
   }

   void main(){
     std::string s1str = "abcdefg"; // Store locally
     Slice s1(s1str);
     printf("%s\n", s1.data());

     auto s2str = get_str(); // Store locally
     Slice s2(s2str);
     printf("%s\n", s2.data());
   }
   ```
2. Continue receiving by value, and store the actual value in your `Slice` (possibly along with the pointer and size, assuming those are mutable, while the `string` is not):

   ```
   Slice {
     // Add string member:
     std::string origstring;
     // Now receives by value, stores it and refers to data in member
     Slice(std::string s): origstring(std::move(s)), data_(origstring.data()), n_(origstring.size()) {}
   }

   std::string get_str(){
     return "abcdefg";
   }

   void main(){
     Slice s1("abcdefg");
     printf("%s\n", s1.data());

     Slice s2(get_str());
     printf("%s\n", s2.data());
   }
   ```

Comment: I would like to with the first version, but is there any way to make the code simpler? e.g. I don't want to define `s1str` and `s2str` first and then use them? I am so lazy that I don't want to add any extra line of code

Comment: What is `data_`?

Comment: @ThomasSablik: Given they're storing a pointer and size, my assumption was that `Slice` was just a view of the string that initially matched the original string, but could have the leading pointer (`data_`) and/or the size (`n_`) adjusted to view a narrower range of the data.

Comment: @MrROY: You can't, without moving to a #2-like solution. Either the caller controls the lifetime of the string (in which case they have to store the string *somewhere*), or the `Slice` does. Closest you could get to an intermediate solution would be some sort of `std::shared_ptr` based approach (where the slice stores an owning reference, and the caller may or may not store an owning reference), but that's going to be more complicated and slower than either of the solutions above, to no real benefit.